# Category Redirection Problem

Tags: categories, redirect

I am trying to redirect all categories at once to a specific page but didn't find any solution.
I go through a solution by redirecting one by one category to a specific page.

So is there any solution to redirect all categories?

Thanks

Comment: use category.php for templating all categories, and redirect from within it?

Comment: Do you actually want to redirect all categories to a specific URL or do you want to load same content for all the categories? These two are not the same thing.

Comment: I have different pages on site, and two parent categoriews with sub categories , so i want on parent category with sub-cat redirection to one page, and same other to another page.

Comment: https://mksapk.com/ Check this link for reference if i want to show different categories at a different locations.